# Start specific instance of bluestacks 5 using command line on windows 11

Tags: command, instance, bluestacks

i have been looking all around but i can't seem to be able to start a specific bluestacks instance using command line.

Basically, i found this question : https://www.reddit.com/r/BlueStacks/comments/x858fc/how_to_close_bluestacks_instance_with_command/

But when i try using hd-player.exe, no matter what i try it only opens the first instance or tells me "unknown option".

I have tried -i for instance/index, -s for start, -a for activate, -r for run, etc but none of them seems to work. Is there anything i am missing or can it simply not be done. I would be fine starting the instance using the instance name or the index. Either way works for me.

Also, i am using bluestacks 5 and lots of infos i find online dont seem to match my current version.

Thx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I tried and it seems to start 4 of my instances in parallel. Hope it helps!

```
start "" "C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt\HD-Player.exe" --instance Nougat64_4
start "" "C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt\HD-Player.exe" --instance Nougat64_2
start "" "C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt\HD-Player.exe" --instance Nougat64
start "" "C:\Program Files\BlueStacks_nxt\HD-Player.exe" --instance Nougat64_1
```

Answer (score 0):

HD-PLAYER.exe doesn't take short form argument, you will need to use `--instance` instead of `-i`. The instance names can be found in bluestacks.conf file, in lines that match `bst.instance.<instance_name>.*`. So if you see a line that says `bst.instance.Pie64.abi_list="x86,x64,arm,arm64"`, The command to start this instance would be:

```
HD-PLAYER.exe --instance Pie64
```